# CTreeCtrl - changing its position without moving the whole area

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, sdi

Helloes and thank you for reading :)

I am writing an application in MFC/SDI. I split the window in two views. The one on the left is derived from CTreeView, the one on the right from CView. I also created an invisible splitter to part them. Here's the picture showing it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFZsz.png (the area on the left is CTreeView derived, my bad). I wanted to move the CTreeCtrl so it doesn't cover the picture. I googled for the possible solution but the only one I found doesn't work quite as I expected. Using GetWindowRect moves the whole area and doesn't allow me to draw on the area that was previously a part of the rectangle but no longer is. So when I move the CTreeCtrl I can't put a picture in the area above it. I am doing all these things in OnInitialUpdate().

Here's a sample code of what I've found on the internet and tried doing:

```
CTreeCtrl &list_recipes = this -> GetTreeCtrl();
list_recipes.GetWindowRect(&rect);
ScreenToClient(&rect);
rect.top += 100;
rect.bottom += 100;
list_recipes.MoveWindow(&rect);

// inserting items into the CTreeCtrl
// (...)

CImage image;
CDC dc;
image.LoadFromResource(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), IDB_CUPCAKE);
dc.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
CRect rect3(0,0,202,126);
image.Draw(pDC -> m_hDC,rect3);
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance :) And I have to use MFC, it wasn't my decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid drawing your image on the treeview. Try using a separate view which contains the treeview and a static control with the treeview moved below.

Comment: I've come up with the same solution just before reading your post, it works and thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of CTreeView you could use CFormView for the left pane. On this form view (which uses a dialog template) put a CTreeCtrl and a CStatic for the picture.